# All combinations of the rows in two data frames

Tags: dataframe, iterator, julia

I have the following two data frames

```
using DataFrames
a = DataFrame(x1=["a";"b";"c"], y1=1:3)
b = DataFrame(x2=["d";"e"], y2=4:5)
```

How can I create a data frame `c` that has all possible combinations of rows in `a` and `b`, i.e.

```
6×4 DataFrame
 Row │ x1      x2      y1     y2    
     │ String  String  Int64  Int64 
─────┼──────────────────────────────
   1 │ a       d           1      4
   2 │ b       d           2      4
   3 │ c       d           3      4
   4 │ a       e           1      5
   5 │ b       e           2      5
   6 │ c       e           3      5
```

There sure must be something more elegant than

```
hcat(rename!(DataFrame(Iterators.product(a.x1, b.x2)), [:x1, :x2]), rename!(DataFrame(Iterators.product(a.y1, b.y2)), [:y1, :y2]))
```

After all, this is quite impractical if I have larger and more complex data frames.

Comment: I think `crossjoin(a,b)` is want you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're looking for `crossjoin`: https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/lib/functions/#DataAPI.crossjoin

```
julia> crossjoin(a,b)
6×4 DataFrame
 Row │ x1      y1     x2      y2
     │ String  Int64  String  Int64
─────┼──────────────────────────────
   1 │ a           1  d           4
   2 │ a           1  e           5
   3 │ b           2  d           4
   4 │ b           2  e           5
   5 │ c           3  d           4
   6 │ c           3  e           5
```